How to set redirect URL with Supabase Auth after OAuth login & PKCE handling (Next.js 14/App Router app)
In my Next.js 14 app with Supabase Auth, I have social login enabled using Supabase's signInWithOAuth method as an server action. This is Server-Side Auth, so I use the PKCE flow by calling signInWIthOAuth with a callback route (/app/auth/callback/route.js) set as the redirectTo option in order to handle code exchange. With this, login works fine.
Now, after authentication, I want to redirect the user back to the page they came from (e.g. If they came from /cart, I want them to be redirected back there. If from /account, redirect to /account). But I can’t figure out how.
In Supabase’ example code, the next variable is defined. (const next = searchParams.get("next") ?? "/" ) and if next exists, it is used as the post-auth/post-code-exchange redirect URL. But I don’t know how to set this next search param.
Here is my code:
In /app/auth/login/actions.js,
"use server"; 

import { redirect } from "next/navigation"; 
import { createClient } from "@/utils/supabase/server"; 

export async function socialLogin(formData) {
  const provider = formData.get("provider"); 
  if (!provider) { 
    return redirect("/login?message=No provider selected"); 
  } 

  const supabase = await createClient(); 
  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
  provider, 
  options: { redirectTo:     "http://localhost:3000/auth/callback", 
  }, 
}); 

  if (error) {  
   return redirect("/login?message=Could not authenticate user");  
  }  
  
  if (data.url) redirect(data.url); 
}

In /app/auth/callback/route.js,
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import { createClient } from "@/utils/supabase/server";

export async function GET(request) {
  const { searchParams, origin } = new URL(request.url); 

  const code = searchParams.get("code"); 
  const next = searchParams.get("next") ?? "/"; 

  if (code) {
    const supabase = await createClient();
    
    const { error } = await supabase.auth.exchangeCodeForSession(code);

    if (!error) {
      const forwardedHost = request.headers.get("x-forwarded-host"); // original origin before load balancer  
      const isLocalEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"; 
      if (isLocalEnv) {
      // we can be sure that there is no load balancer in between, so no need to watch for X-Forwarded-Host 
        return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}${next}`);
      } else if (forwardedHost) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(`https://${forwardedHost}${next}`);
      } else {
      return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}${next}`);
      }
    }
  } 

return NextResponse.redirect( `${origin}/login?message=Could not login with provider`, ); 
}

In OAuth provider’s console (e.g. Google Cloud console), I’ve entered the callback URL from the Supabase dashboard (i.e. <PROJECT_ID>.supabase.co/auth/v1/callback), per Supabase documentation.
In Supabase dashboard, I set redirect URLs as follows:
Supabase dashboard Redirect URLs
Again, social login itself works fine. But after authentication, as next does not exist, the user is always redirected to /.
I'd appreciate your help!

SOLVED: someone pointed out that I just had to add a query param in my redirectTo such that
redirectTo: "http://localhost:3000/auth/callback?next=/cart"

